# ExtJs 3 : Change cell background color of a grid

Tags: json, extjs, grid

I have an extJs(3.0) grid panel whick is loaded from postgresql database using json. This is my grid panel code segment:

```
var drop_pick_grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
store : dropPickGridStore,
cm : new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([ selectModel, {
    sortable : true,
    header : "Drop/Pick Loc",
    dataIndex : 'locationName',
    width : 170
}, {
    header : "Town/City",
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'city',
    width : 120
}, {
    header : "Address",
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'addr',
    width : 170
}, {
    header : "EST.Un/Load Time",
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'estimatedTime',
    width : 100
} ]),
sm : selectModel,
/*viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, index) {
        var color = record.get('tourTypeColor');
        if (c == 'Kandy') {
            alert('Kandy');
        }
    }
},*/
//width : 570,
//height : 390,
autoHeight : true,
autoWidth : true,
frame : true,
iconCls : 'icon-grid',
renderTo : document.body
});
```

My Json data :

```
{'dropPickLoc':[{ 'locationName' : 'Gayan Hardware', 'city' : 'Galle', 'addr' : '121, Wijaya Rd, Galle', 'estimatedTime' : '120', 'tourTypeColor' : 'blue' } , { 'locationName' : 'Kandy Hardware', 'city' : 'Kandy', 'addr' : '11, Kurunagala Road, Kandy', 'estimatedTime' : '40', 'tourTypeColor' : 'blue' } , { 'locationName' : 'Mala Stores', 'city' : 'Colombo', 'addr' : '11B, Thimbirigasyaya, Colombo', 'estimatedTime' : '45', 'tourTypeColor' : 'yellow' } , { 'locationName' : 'Namal Ceramic', 'city' : 'Kurunagala', 'addr' : '12B, Lumbini Udyanaya, Kurinagala', 'estimatedTime' : '45', 'tourTypeColor' : 'yellow' } , { 'locationName' : 'Priya Ceramic', 'city' : 'Nugegoda', 'addr' : '15, Nugegoda', 'estimatedTime' : '40', 'tourTypeColor' : 'yellow' } , { 'locationName' : 'Sam Stores', 'city' : 'Galle', 'addr' : '46A, Galle', 'estimatedTime' : '120', 'tourTypeColor' : 'green' } , { 'locationName' : 'Saman Stores', 'city' : 'Polgahawela', 'addr' : '111, Kurunagala Rd, Kurunagala', 'estimatedTime' : '120', 'tourTypeColor' : 'blue' } , { 'locationName' : 'Sell-X Computors', 'city' : 'Ratnapura', 'addr' : '12, Tiriwanakatiya, Ratnapura', 'estimatedTime' : '120', 'tourTypeColor' : 'green' } , { 'locationName' : 'Super Stores', 'city' : 'Kandy', 'addr' : '16, Kandy Road', 'estimatedTime' : '120', 'tourTypeColor' : 'blue' } , { 'locationName' : 'Wijesingha Hardware', 'city' : 'Galle', 'addr' : '113A, Wackewella Road, Galle', 'estimatedTime' : '120', 'tourTypeColor' : 'green' } ]}
```

The grid is loaded successfully. Now I need to change background color of "Location Name" column. According to my Json data every location name has a **tourTypeColor**. I need to change each and every location name cell according to this color.

Any suggestions are appreiated. please help me with some code segments.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that firm in using ExtJS 3.

I would try to define a rendere for your column "Drop/Pick Loc" like this:

```
{
    sortable : true,
    header : "Drop/Pick Loc",
    dataIndex : 'locationName',
    width : 170,
    renderer : function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {

                   metaData.attr = 'style="color:' + record.get('tourTypeColor') + ';"';
                   return value;
               }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply Michel but it doesn't do anything

Comment: And no error occurs? Can't be that wrong :) Here I took some example i found and it works http://jsfiddle.net/MichelH/F9QM7/1/ I did not have the correct css right now.

Comment: I doesn't add tourTypeColor into my grid.Is that why it's not working?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44774/discussion-between-michel-and-ann18)

Comment: Thanx Michel. This is working. I don't need to add , {
  dataIndex : 'tourTypeColor'
 }.The thing is I missed something.I forgot to add tourTypeColor to my store.Thanx for your help.Your code is working.